# Using EWS how to get the meeting organizer working hours start and end time

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013, exchangewebservices

I am using the EWS managed API to pull data from Exchange to a sharePoint application. I am usign the GetUserAvailability method to retrieve the information. Unfortunatly exchange is returning time even outside business hours. The problem is more evident when lets say organizer is in EST and attendee is in Australia time. Both of their working hour is set to local time in there country for example 8 AM to 5 PM local time. So when searching for a common time there should not be any overlap but exchange return the time considering the organizers time zone, which is not the expected outcome. The below code is given for reference.

```
public List<Week> RefineParams(string strLoginID, string strUserIds, DateTime StartTime, DateTime EndTime, int intNumberOfWeeks, int intMeetDur, bool includeNonBusHr, string strTimeZoneOffSet, string upn)
        {
            List<Week> weeks = null;
            try
            {
                KGSGLogger.LogError(SPCustomCategory.kGSGService.ToString(), "RefineParams started");
                ExchangeService _ews = null;
                string strTimeZoneID = GetTimeZoneStringFromOffset(strTimeZoneOffSet);

                _ews = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(strTimeZoneID));

                // Override certificate check (due to lab environment using self-signed certs)
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);

                string name = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

                KGSGLogger.LogError(SPCustomCategory.kGSGService.ToString(), "EWS Credential  " + System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name + "Authentication Type " + System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().AuthenticationType);


                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {

                    //IClaimsIdentity identity = (ClaimsIdentity)Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity;
                    //string upn = null;
                    //foreach (Claim claim in identity.Claims)
                    //{
                    //    if (StringComparer.Ordinal.Equals(ClaimTypes.Upn, claim.ClaimType))
                    //    {
                    //        upn = claim.Value;
                    //        KGSGLogger.LogError(SPCustomCategory.kGSGService.ToString(), " UPN Value= " + upn + " for user: " + name);
                    //    }
                    //}

                    // Perform the UPN logon through the c2WTS.
                    WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity = null;
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(upn))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            windowsIdentity = S4UClient.UpnLogon(upn);
                            if (windowsIdentity != null)
                            {
                                KGSGLogger.LogError(SPCustomCategory.kGSGService.ToString(), "Windows indentity created for UPN: " + upn);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                KGSGLogger.LogError(SPCustomCategory.kGSGService.ToString(), "Failed to create Windows indentity");
                            }
                        }
                        catch (SecurityAccessDeniedException)
                        {
                            KGSGLogger.LogError(SPCustomCategory.kGSGService.ToString(), "Could not map the upn claim to a valid windows identity.name : " + name);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        KGSGLogger.LogError(SPCustomCategory.kGSGService.ToString(), "Refine Params: No UPN claim found");
                        throw new Exception("No UPN claim found");
                    }
                    KGSGLogger.LogError(SPCustomCategory.kGSGService.ToString(), "Before impeosonation Thread.Current.Name: " + Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name);
                    KGSGLogger.LogError(SPCustomCategory.kGSGService.ToString(), "Before impeosonation WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);

                    string strOrganizer = GetEmailForLoginName(strLoginID);
                    string strAttendeeEmails = GetEmailForUserID(strUserIds);

                    using (WindowsImpersonationContext ctxt = windowsIdentity.Impersonate())
                    {
                        KGSGLogger.LogError(SPCustomCategory.kGSGService.ToString(), "After impeosonation Thread.Current.Name: " + Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name);
                        KGSGLogger.LogError(SPCustomCategory.kGSGService.ToString(), "After impeosonation WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);

                        string strEWSServiceURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("EWSServiceURL");
                        KGSGLogger.LogError(SPCustomCategory.kGSGService.ToString(), "EWS URL " + strEWSServiceURL);
                        _ews.Url = new Uri(strEWSServiceURL);

                        // Create a list of attendees.
                        List<AttendeeInfo> attendees = new List<AttendeeInfo>();

                        string[] arrUserID = null;
                        strUserIds = strUserIds.Trim(',');


                        arrUserID = strAttendeeEmails.Split(',');
                        attendees.Add(new AttendeeInfo()
                        {
                            //email address.
                            SmtpAddress = strOrganizer,
                            AttendeeType = MeetingAttendeeType.Organizer,
                            ExcludeConflicts = true
                        });

                        for (int i = 0; i < arrUserID.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(arrUserID[i]) && arrUserID[i].Contains("@"))
                            {
                                attendees.Add(new AttendeeInfo()
                                {
                                    //email address.
                                    SmtpAddress = Convert.ToString(arrUserID[i]),
                                    AttendeeType = MeetingAttendeeType.Required,
                                    ExcludeConflicts = true
                                });
                            }
                        }
                        foreach (AttendeeInfo aa in attendees)
                        {
                            KGSGLogger.LogError(SPCustomCategory.kGSGService.ToString(), "Attendee " + aa.SmtpAddress + "Attendeee type "+ aa.AttendeeType);
                        }
                        // Specify suggested meeting time options.
                        AvailabilityOptions meetingOptions = new AvailabilityOptions();
                        meetingOptions.MeetingDuration = intMeetDur;
                        if (includeNonBusHr)
                        {
                            KGSGLogger.LogError(SPCustomCategory.kGSGService.ToString(), "Viewing business hours "+includeNonBusHr);
                            meetingOptions.MaximumNonWorkHoursSuggestionsPerDay = 48;
                            meetingOptions.MaximumSuggestionsPerDay = 48;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            KGSGLogger.LogError(SPCustomCategory.kGSGService.ToString(), "Viewing business hours " + includeNonBusHr);
                            meetingOptions.MaximumNonWorkHoursSuggestionsPerDay = 0;
                            meetingOptions.MaximumSuggestionsPerDay = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("MaximumSuggestionsPerDay"));
                            KGSGLogger.LogError(SPCustomCategory.kGSGService.ToString(), "MaximumSuggestionsPerDay " + meetingOptions.MaximumSuggestionsPerDay);
                        }
                        meetingOptions.GoodSuggestionThreshold = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("GoodSuggestionThreshold"));
                        KGSGLogger.LogError(SPCustomCategory.kGSGService.ToString(), "MaximumSuggestionsPerDay " + meetingOptions.GoodSuggestionThreshold);
                        meetingOptions.MinimumSuggestionQuality = SuggestionQuality.Good;
                        EndTime = EndTime.AddDays(1);
                        meetingOptions.DetailedSuggestionsWindow = new TimeWindow(StartTime, EndTime);
                        meetingOptions.RequestedFreeBusyView = FreeBusyViewType.FreeBusy;
                        // Return a set of of suggested meeting times.
                        GetUserAvailabilityResults results = _ews.GetUserAvailability(attendees,
                                                                                      new TimeWindow(StartTime, EndTime),
                                                                                          AvailabilityData.FreeBusyAndSuggestions,
                                                                                          meetingOptions);                        
                        weeks = new List<Week>();
                        List<DateTime> mtTimesColl = new List<DateTime>();

                        if (results != null)
                        {
                            foreach (Suggestion suggestion in results.Suggestions)
                            {
                                int cnt = suggestion.TimeSuggestions.Count;
                                foreach (TimeSuggestion tmesugg in suggestion.TimeSuggestions)
                                {
                                    if (tmesugg.MeetingTime != null)
                                    {
                                        KGSGLogger.LogError(SPCustomCategory.kGSGService.ToString(), "ConsiderTimeZone Value " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConsiderTimeZone"].ToString().Trim().ToLower());
                                        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConsiderTimeZone"].ToString().Trim().ToLower().CompareTo("true")==0)
                                        {
                                            KGSGLogger.LogError(SPCustomCategory.kGSGService.ToString(), "Within if statement : ConsiderTimeZone");
                                            //List<ArrayList> attendeeColl = new List<ArrayList>();
                                            List<List<DateTime>> attendeeColl = new List<List<DateTime>>();

                                            if (results.AttendeesAvailability[0] != null)
                                            {
                                                KGSGLogger.LogError(SPCustomCategory.kGSGService.ToString(), "Organizer object found");
                                                if (results.AttendeesAvailability[0].WorkingHours != null)
                                                {
                                                    KGSGLogger.LogError(SPCustomCategory.kGSGService.ToString(), "WorkingHours " + results.AttendeesAvailability[0].WorkingHours.ToString());
                                                    if (results.AttendeesAvailability[0].WorkingHours.TimeZone != null)
                                                    {
                                                        KGSGLogger.LogError(SPCustomCategory.kGSGService.ToString(), "Time Zone " + results.AttendeesAvailability[0].WorkingHours.TimeZone.ToString());
                                                        if (results.AttendeesAvailability[0].WorkingHours.TimeZone.BaseUtcOffset != null)
                                                        {
                                                            KGSGLogger.LogError(SPCustomCategory.kGSGService.ToString(), "base utc" + results.AttendeesAvailability[0].WorkingHours.TimeZone.BaseUtcOffset.ToString());
                                                            KGSGLogger.LogError(SPCustomCategory.kGSGService.ToString(), "within base utc off set not null");
                                                            var organizerTimeZone = results.AttendeesAvailability[0].WorkingHours.TimeZone.BaseUtcOffset;
                                                            KGSGLogger.LogError("Organizer time zone: ", organizerTimeZone.ToString());//till here
                                                            foreach (AttendeeAvailability aa in results.AttendeesAvailability)
                                                            {
                                                                //ArrayList singleAttendeeSlots = new ArrayList();
                                                                List<DateTime> singleAttendeeSlots = new List<DateTime>();
                                                                //var singleAttendeeSlots = new ArrayList();
                                                                KGSGLogger.LogError("Atteendee timezone base offset", (aa.WorkingHours.TimeZone.BaseUtcOffset.ToString()));
                                                                KGSGLogger.LogError("Converted start time to organizer timezone ", (Convert.ToDateTime(aa.WorkingHours.StartTime.ToString()).Add(organizerTimeZone - aa.WorkingHours.TimeZone.BaseUtcOffset)).ToString());
                                                                KGSGLogger.LogError("Converted end time to organizer timezone ", (Convert.ToDateTime(aa.WorkingHours.EndTime.ToString()).Add(organizerTimeZone - aa.WorkingHours.TimeZone.BaseUtcOffset)).ToString());
                                                                if ((Convert.ToDateTime(results.AttendeesAvailability[0].WorkingHours.StartTime.ToString())
                                                                    <= (Convert.ToDateTime(aa.WorkingHours.StartTime.ToString()).Add(organizerTimeZone - aa.WorkingHours.TimeZone.BaseUtcOffset)))
                                                                    && (Convert.ToDateTime(results.AttendeesAvailability[0].WorkingHours.EndTime.ToString()))
                                                                    >= (Convert.ToDateTime(aa.WorkingHours.EndTime.ToString()).Add(organizerTimeZone - aa.WorkingHours.TimeZone.BaseUtcOffset)))
                                                                {

                                                                    DateTime dtConv = tmesugg.MeetingTime;
                                                                    //mtTimesColl.Add(dtConv);
                                                                    singleAttendeeSlots.Add(dtConv);
                                                                    KGSGLogger.LogError("TimeZone consideration taken ", dtConv.ToString());
                                                                }
                                                                attendeeColl.Add(singleAttendeeSlots);
                                                            }
                                                            var TimeSLots = attendeeColl.Cast<IEnumerable<DateTime>>().Aggregate((x, y) => x.Intersect(y));
                                                            foreach (DateTime meetingTime in TimeSLots)
                                                            {
                                                                mtTimesColl.Add(meetingTime);
                                                                KGSGLogger.LogError("meeting slots ", meetingTime.ToString());
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                            KGSGLogger.LogError(SPCustomCategory.kGSGService.ToString(), "base utc is null");
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        KGSGLogger.LogError(SPCustomCategory.kGSGService.ToString(), "Time ZOne is null");
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    KGSGLogger.LogError(SPCustomCategory.kGSGService.ToString(), "WorkingHours is null");
                                                }
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                KGSGLogger.LogError(SPCustomCategory.kGSGService.ToString(), "organizer is null");

                                            }                                                                                        
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            KGSGLogger.LogError(SPCustomCategory.kGSGMeetingScheduler.ToString(),
                                                "Within else statement : ConsiderTimeZone");
                                            if (results.AttendeesAvailability[0].WorkingHours != null)
                                            {
                                                DateTime dtConv = tmesugg.MeetingTime;
                                                mtTimesColl.Add(dtConv);
                                                KGSGLogger.LogError("NO TIMEZONE CONVERSION Available slot: ", dtConv.ToString());
                                            }

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            mtTimesColl.Sort((x, y) => x.CompareTo(y));
                            weeks.Add(GetAvailableSlots(StartTime, EndTime, intNumberOfWeeks, mtTimesColl));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            KGSGLogger.LogError(SPCustomCategory.kGSGService.ToString(), "Refine Params: GetUserAvailabilityResults is null");
                            throw new Exception("Refine Params: GetUserAvailabilityResults is null");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                KGSGLogger.LogError(SPCustomCategory.kGSGService.ToString(), string.Format("Error in RefineParams(); " + "{0}/n{1}/n{2}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace ?? string.Empty, ex.InnerException == null ? string.Empty : ex.InnerException.Message));

            }
            KGSGLogger.LogError(SPCustomCategory.kGSGService.ToString(), "RefineParams ends");
            return weeks;
        }
```

Comment: "So when searching for a common time there should not be any overlap but exchange return the time considering the organizers time zone" isn't that exactly what you want? -> no overlap? If not, could you post some concrete example time frames you get back and tell what you had expected instead?

Comment: Lets say there are three people in a meeting: one organizer and two other attendees and all of them are in different time zone. So exchange should return the intersection of their available time which lies within the working hour of all of them. If they have no overlap in their working hour there should not be any time slot common to any of them.

Comment: Earlier I would get the working hour for the organizer but now it is returning null. (results.AttendeesAvailability[0].WorkingHours != null). Is this related to any configuration on the exchange server side?